Canadian: No sound when calling US numbers
My Phone is a Moto g7 Play.
My provider is Koodo (a brand of the Canadian Telus), I am dialing from Canada.
My account includes the following feature:

Unlimited Long Distance Pack
Get unlimited long distance calling to 27 countries including the US, China, Hong Kong, India, Mexico, Bangladesh, and the UK from anywhere in Canada.

When I dial a US number, the call goes through, but there is no sound on my end. I don't hear the ringing tones, the other party, nothing; though once the call connects the other party hears me.
Accepting calls (from Canada or the US) works fine. Dialing Canadian numbers works fine. Dialing UK numbers works fine. Dialing a number in a country not in the "Unlimited Long Distance Pack" works fine. Dialing a US toll-free (1-800, 1-888, etc.) number appears to work - I don't hear any ringing tones, but I do hear the message from the other side of the line.
It seems that only dialing US non-toll-free numbers has this issue.
But here's the kicker: if I put my SIM in a different phone, it works without an issue.
What can cause this strange behaviour?

Edit:
Turning VoLTE off solved the issue. Then I tried WiFi calling, and it exhibited the same issue.
So it looks like a VoIP issue (as @Robert suggested in the comments).
I now have a workaround, except that I cannot use it when I don't have 3G connectivity.
The question is whether it can be solved in a better way, either on my end or by the provider.

Edit 2:
I had a chat with Telus tech support.
Apparently it is a known problem that affects several phone models on their network.
There’s a workaround: pausing and resuming the call restores the sound (for that call).
They opened a ticket for me too, so maybe a permanent solution will be found.

My guess would be a codec problem. Some US systems seems to use an audio codec your phone doesn't support or that doesn't work correctly, therefore you don't hear anything.

@Robert, that would not explain why I hear them when they call me, it's only the outgoing calls that exhibit the problem.

In VoIP communication there are two streams, one from your phone (through several VoIP servers) to the target phone and the other way around.  I am not a VoIP expert but I assume that for each stream the used codec can be different. And the intermediate VoIP servers can even re-encode the audio stream to use a different codec on both sides of their connection. As you can see there are a lot of weak points where something can go wrong so that you end up with a one-directional phone call.

@Robert, it seems that you were right and it is a VoIP issue. The question is whether it can be solved, either on my end or by the provider.
