Phone calls don't go through with some numbers
I have an Android phone (Samsung Galaxy Note 8, Andorid Version 9) which works fine but on some specific numbers, it does not seem to be able to establish a connection. I hear the first tone (or at least part of it) indicating a connection has been made but afterward, there is only silence until the phone hangs up after about 35 seconds (it's always the same time).
Curiously the phone works fine with a different SIM card. Putting the original SIM card from the phone into a different phone works as well. Does anyone have any hints on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Most likely a codec problem of the used VoIP Connection. See also the similar question https://android.stackexchange.com/q/258913/2241

@Robert thanks, turning off VoLTE did the trick, the second workaround (pausing the call) doesn't work, since the phone doesn't establish a connection. Feel free to write an answer.

Hi Robert, you can write up the answer instead and you are allowed to tick it after 24hrs.

@RohitGupta do you mean Robert or myself?

Note that turning off VoLTE only works if the network you are in still has 2G or 3G capability. Also without VoLTE your Internet will be off while on a call

@Robert good points, thank you
